# Firefox update fails; "Could not get lock" error when I run sudo apt upgrade

Tags: apt, firefox, dpkg, mate

I am new to Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu MATE in my p.c. Now when I opened browser Mozilla Firefox it searched for a update. So I have been updating it but it fails every time.

`sudo apt update` works well.

`sudo apt upgrade` throws this error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

How can I update all the applications in Ubuntu MATE as well as Mozilla Firefox?

Comment: I am using ubuntu mate.I don't think ubuntu mate and ubuntu work in same way. Ubutu mate is a lighter version compare to Ubuntu. So definitely there are some software issues.

Comment: **sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock ** After given that command I got **lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
unattende 4937 root    4uW  REG    8,1        0 2098137 /var/lib/dpkg/lock**  What does it mean?

Comment: Because Mate is lighter version.

Comment: There is no difference between Ubuntu MATE and Ubuntu that is relevant to anything in your question. It seems the underlying issue here is with Firefox. APT will update firefox along with all other packages Reboot and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove` and then please let us know if you still have any problems with Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Use this with care, i.e. make sure not other installation/upgrade is running in parallel.

You can try sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock.

It should remove the lock and allow for upgrade.

Edit:

To check whether any other installation is running, try

ps -ef | grep apt

ps -ef | grep dpkg

and see if any processes are listed, if same are present, check if any other open terminal is running any installation.

Hope it helps.